# XSLT match for node and descendants

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML example:

```
<root>
    <Customer>
        <Name/>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine1/>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <AddressLine3/>
        </Address>
    </Customer>
    <Provider>
        <Region>
            <County/>
        </Region>
        <HeadOffice>
            <Address>
                <Line1/>
                <Line2/>
                <Postcode>
                    <Sector/>
                </Postcode>
            </Address>
        </HeadOffice>
    </Provider>
</root>
```

I want to add an attribute to the `Address` elements and all descendant elements, so that my output would look like this:

```
<root>
    <Customer>
        <Name/>
        <Address defer="true">
            <AddressLine1 defer="true"/>
            <AddressLine2 defer="true"/>
            <AddressLine3 defer="true"/>
        </Address>
    </Customer>
    <Provider>
        <Region>
            <County/>
        </Region>
        <HeadOffice>
            <Address defer="true">
                <Line1 defer="true"/>
                <Line2 defer="true"/>
                <Postcode defer="true">
                    <Sector defer="true"/>
                </Postcode>
            </Address>
        </HeadOffice>
    </Provider>
</root>
```

The `Address` element may have different parents and varying descendants but I always want to add the attribute to it and all of its descendants.

I've got this XSLT that does the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Address|Address//*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:attribute name="defer">true</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the `<xsl:template match="Address|Address//*">` feels clunky.

Is there a better/more elegant way of matching an element and all of its descendants or is this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `match="Address|Address//*"` is the proper way to express a match of any `Address` element and of any possible descendant elements of `Address` elements. I don't see why it is clunky or not elegant. You could change the `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">` to `<xsl:copy>` in my view to have a more elegant way to copy the matched element, but of course elegance is rather a personal judgement.

Comment: I guess I thought it was clunky because I needed to specify the `Address` twice - I wondered whether I was missing a less repetitive method that only had to specify the element name once. Many thanks for the `<xsl:copy>` tip though - you're right, it's much better!

Answer (score 1):

One of rules concerning performance in XSLT is to avoid "//" in XPaths.
So if performance is an issue, you could use the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::Address]">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:attribute name="defer">true</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note also that `apply-templates` in the second template has `select` attribute.
If you omit it, you will lose other attributes (if any).